# How to reassign value to a null value output from a Map

Tags: go

I have a map imageFiles which is being populated

```
var imageFiles map[Image][]*File
imageFiles = getImageFiles(data)
for image := range images {
    file = imageFiles[image]
    print file[0].Name
}
```

I get this error when file is empty. file = [] (when I print it)

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
```

File is a struct

```
type File struct {
    Name    string 
    Size     string 
    Title   string 
}
```

Is there a way for me to ensure that I can put some default value into file (say empty strings )so that this can be avoided?)

Comment: No. You have to check `len(file)`.

Comment: But if you check the len can you reassign after that?

Answer (score 2):

You map an `Image` to a slice of pointers to a File `[]*File`. The default/empty value for slices is nil. All indexes are "out of range" when the slice is nil.

Your options are:

1. modify `getImageFiles` to return a slice containing at least one items;
2. add code to check the length of the slice:

   ```golang
   for image := range images {
       file = imageFiles[image]
       if len(file) == 0 {
           // do something here
           continue
       }
       print file[0].Name
   }
   ```
3. Create a new type for the file slice that hides the underlying implementation:

   ```golang
   type FileList []*File

   func (f FileList) FirstName() string {
       if f == nil || len(f) == 0 {
           return ""
       }
       return f[0].Name
   }

   var imageFiles map[Image]FileList
   imageFiles = getImageFiles(data)
   for image := range images {
       file = imageFiles[image]
       print file.FirstName()
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to modify the file inside the if len(file) == 0  condition and add a value to it?

Comment: Not really because `file[0]` doesn't exist. `file` is empty.